# Join elements by iterating through the data

Tags: python, r, matlab, gis

I have some data in the form:

```
ID A B VALUE         EXPECTED RESULT
1  1 2 5               GROUP1
2  2 3 5               GROUP1
3  3 4 6               GROUP2
4  3 5 5               GROUP1
5  6 4 5               GROUP3
```

What i want to do is iterate through the data (thousand of rows) and create a common field so i will be able to join the data easily ( *A-> start Node, B->End Node Value-> Order...the data form something like a chain where only neighbors share a common A or B)

Rules for joining:

1. equal value for all elements of a group
2. A of element one equal to B of element two (or the oposite but NOT A=A' or B=B')
3. The most difficult one: assign to same group all sequential data that form a series of intersecting nodes.

That is the first element [1 1 2 5] has to be joined with [2 2 3 5] and then with [4 3 5 5]

Any idea how to accomplish this robustly when iterating through a large number of data? I have problem with rule number 3, the others are easily applied. For limited data i have some success, but this depends on the order i start examining the data. And this doesn't work for the large dataset.
I can use arcpy (preferably) or even Python or R or Matlab to solve this. **Have tried arcpy with no success so i am checking on alternatives.**

In ArcPy this code works ok but to limited extend (i.e. in large features with many segments i get 3-4 groups instead of 1):

```
TheShapefile="c:/Temp/temp.shp"
desc = arcpy.Describe(TheShapefile)
flds = desc.fields
fldin = 'no'
for fld in flds:        #Check if new field exists
    if fld.name == 'new':
        fldin = 'yes'
if fldin!='yes':                    #If not create
    arcpy.AddField_management(TheShapefile, "new", "SHORT")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(TheShapefile,"new",'!FID!', "PYTHON_9.3")  # Copy FID to new
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(TheShapefile, ["FID","NODE_A","NODE_B","ORDER_","new"]) as TheSearch:
    for SearchRow in TheSearch:
        if SearchRow[1]==SearchRow[4]:
            Outer_FID=SearchRow[0]
        else:
            Outer_FID=SearchRow[4]
        Outer_NODEA=SearchRow[1]
        Outer_NODEB=SearchRow[2]
        Outer_ORDER=SearchRow[3]
        Outer_NEW=SearchRow[4]
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(TheShapefile, ["FID","NODE_A","NODE_B","ORDER_","new"]) as TheUpdate:
                    for UpdateRow in TheUpdate:
                        Inner_FID=UpdateRow[0]
                        Inner_NODEA=UpdateRow[1]
                        Inner_NODEB=UpdateRow[2]
                        Inner_ORDER=UpdateRow[3]
                        if Inner_ORDER==Outer_ORDER and (Inner_NODEA==Outer_NODEB or Inner_NODEB==Outer_NODEA):
                            UpdateRow[4]=Outer_FID
                            TheUpdate.updateRow(UpdateRow)
```

And some data in [shapefile form and dbf form](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkmYF_SsN2i-k-tM8_JKmOY0jdZpQA?e=bgyGD6)

Comment: R, python or matlab??

Comment: Preferably Python.. However i can use other languages to solve the problem. I just need it solved. (Yes i have asked again for Python and no reply after days of waiting so maybe in Python it is difficult to implement?)

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far. And please provide the data in some structure, not human-readable table - how are we supposed to know what are you using to store it?

Comment: I do not think that it deserves DV, but I cannot imagine a simple and rapid way. Maybe you should show a honest attempt to prove your prior research, and help others with the first elements of a program.

Comment: I have added my attempts in arcpy. It uses python at its base, but i am new at python in general so i would have trouble transferring the code to Python.

Comment: This appears to be some form of graphing problem.  However, I don't see why node 5 is not connected to group 1, as it has the value of 5 and points to node 3, already in the group.  Is this from the ordering?  Is it not permissible to "back up" to a previous node?

Comment: You are right. It was a typo error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using matlab:

```matlab
A = [1 1 2 5               
     2 2 3 5               
     3 3 4 6               
     4 3 5 5
     5 6 4 5]               

%% Initialization
% index of matrix line sharing the same group     
ind = 1 
% length of the index
len = length(ind)
% the group array
g   = []
% group counter
c   = 1

% Start the small algorithm
while 1
    % Check if another line with the same "Value" share some common node
    ind = find(any(ismember(A(:,2:3),A(ind,2:3)) & A(:,4) == A(ind(end),4),2));

    % If there is no new line, we create a group with the discovered line
    if length(ind) == len
        %group assignment
        g(A(ind,1)) = c
        c = c+1
        % delete the already discovered line (or node...)
        A(ind,:) = []
        % break if no more node
        if isempty(A)
            break
        end
        % reset the index for the next group
        ind = 1;
    end
    len = length(ind);
end
```

And here is the output:

```
g =

   1   1   2   1   3
```

As expected

Comment: Thank you! I am running the code on the full dataset now! Fingers crossed it will work!

Comment: Tested it! It took some time but everything worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You welcome ! Yeah, I've not really optimized this algorithm. If you're curisous and If all your node have a geometry, you could also create a feature of multipoint geometry (each of them will contains the 2 nodes) and use the DBSCAN algorithm, with a search distance = 0, to create your cluster. There is an implementation of those algorithm in [arcpy](https://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/densitybasedclustering.htm), this algorithm is amazingly fast.